# How to prove that: let $n$ a natural odd, then prove that $x^n<y^n$ iff $x<y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

I tried it in many ways but I couldn't prove it.
  **TASK:**
 Let $n$ a **natural odd**, $\ \ x,y\in\mathbb{R},$ then prove that $x^n<y^n$ iff $x<y$

***My Attempt(s):*** $$\begin{align} & x^n<y^n \\ \Longleftrightarrow{} &  x^n-y^n<0 \\ \Longleftrightarrow{} & (x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-k-1}y^k<0 \end{align}$$ And I'm stuck here.

Thus, I can't solve it with induction either. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just so we're clear, $x, y$ can be any real numbers, correct?

Comment: @NobleMushtak $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user251257 do you have time to help me even more ? I don't know how to "factor out" $x^n.$

Answer (score 1):

It is better to prove that $f(x) = x^{n}$ (where $n$ is odd positive integer) is strictly increasing on both intervals $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$ and this will imply that it is strictly increasing on whole of $\mathbb{R}$. The fact that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0, \infty)$ is obvious for the very reason that if $x, y \in [0, \infty)$ and $x < y$ then $y$ is strictly positive and $x$ is non-negative so that $$f(x) - f(y) = (x - y)\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}x^{n - 1 - k}y^{k} < 0$$ Let's check what happens on interval $(-\infty, 0]$. If $x, y \in (-\infty, 0]$ and $x < y$ then $x$ is strictly negative whereas $y$ is non-positive. Again we have $$f(x) - f(y) = (x - y)\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}x^{n - 1 - k}y^{k}$$ Note that the sum $\sum x^{n - 1 - k}y^{k}$ has terms where powers of $x, y$ have same parity (because their powers add up to $(n - 1)$ which is even). So if both the powers are even then the term is obviously non-negative. And if both the powers are odd then the term is product of two non-positive numbers and hence it is again non-negative. Thus each term in the sum $\sum x^{n - 1 - k}y^{k}$ is non-negative. Moreover first term $x^{n - 1}$ is positive because $x$ is negative and $n - 1$ is even. So the whole sum is positive and therefore $$f(x) - f(y) = (x - y)\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}x^{n - 1 - k}y^{k} < 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You are half-way there.

Your approach is clearly sufficient if $x$ and $y$ are both $> 0$, because then $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-k-1}y^k$ is strictly positive.

Now you need to show that if $x < 0$, then $x^n < 0$. Then you can just consider all the different cases of $x,y$ being strictly positive, strictly negative, and zero.

Comment: What happens when $x<0<y$ ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis if $x^n$ is negative, then $x<0$, because $x^n = x \cdot x^{n-1}$ and $x^{n-1}$ is always nonnegative since $n-1$ is even (a more rigorous proof of this can use the fact that $$x^{n-1} = \prod^{k} x^2$$ and exploit the trivial inequality).  Similarly, if $y^n > 0$, $y>0$. And so $x<0<y$.

The other side of the biconditional is similar. We simply multiply the inequality $x<0$ by $x^{n-1}$ and $y>0$ by $y^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start by proving the simpler, but easier version of the problem. If $0\leq x < y$, then $x^n<y^n$, for all natural numbers $n$. (You can easily prove this using induction.)

**Hint:** Realize that every number $x$ can be written as $x=\rm{sgn}(x) \cdot |x|$, where $\rm{sgn}(x)$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). In particular, notice that if $n$ is odd, then
$$\rm{sgn}(x)^n=\rm{sgn}(x)$$

You can now divide it into 4 cases:

> $x<0,y<0$
>
> $x<0,y\geq0$
>
> $x\geq0,y<0$, but this case never happens since then $x>y$.
>
> $x\geq0,y\geq0$, but you already proved this.

You can prove these two cases by writing $x=\rm{sgn}(x) \cdot |x|$ and $y=\rm{sgn}(y) \cdot |y|$, and using induction over $n$. Just be careful that now you need to prove that if the proposition is true for the odd natural $k$, then it is true for $k+2$ (which is the next odd natural number).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

By induction you can show that $x^n > 0$ holds for any $x>0$ and $(-1)^n = -1$ for odd $n$.

Prove the case $0\le x < y$ as you did.

The case $x \le 0 < y$ is trivial as $x^n = -(-x)^n$ is non positive and $y^n$ is positive.

The case $x < y \le 0$ use
$$ -x^n = (-x)^n > (-y)^n = -y^n. $$

Fill the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is elementary to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n−1}x^{n−k−1}y^k\geq \frac{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}}{2},$ provided $n$ is an odd natural number. With this, the desired result follows.

Answer (score -1):

What about considering function f(x) = x^n which is increasing function.

It means that for x < y -> f(x) < f(y).

So x^n < y^n

Comment: When you say that $f(x)=x^n$ is an increasing function (which is only true if $n$ is odd, by the way), you are assuming the thing that you have to prove!

Comment: That doesn't prove anything at all.

Comment: It's very natural to try and appeal to calculus, but keep in mind that the derivative is not strictly positive, so it is not entirely trivial.